# Is it wrong to say "Litter rubbish"?

Tags: usage, idiomatic-language

While littering means throwing away rubbish, is it wrong to say, "Don't litter rubbish?", or just "Don't litter."?

Answer (score 3):

Normally the direct object of transitive verb **litter** is that which has rubbish strewn upon it:

> Don't litter the sidewalk with your cigarette butts.
>
> The crime scene was littered with spent shotgun shells.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the transitivity. It might also be interesting to note that litter can also be intransitive.

Answer (score 0):

Just say "Don't litter".  You are correct that in saying 'Don't litter rubbish' that the word rubbish would be superfluous.

Comment: Interesting that "litter" can be a verb or a noun, but we don't consider "rubbish" to be a verb.

Comment: But **trash** can go either way.

Comment: @MikeKozar *Rubbish* in British English can be used as a verb the same as *trash* in North American English in the sense of abusing someone or something as if they are worthless, but not of scattering litter, e.g. *rubbishing* an idea or a reputation.